# Testing with rosmake -a -t fails because a test failure failed to launch. What's wrong?

Tags: navigation, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running 'rosmake -a -t' I get some test failures attributed to 'Test Fixture Nodes ['xxx'] failed to launch. How can I determine what's wrong and fix it?

An abbreviated example:

> ERRORS/FAILURES:
> [robot_pose_ekf.rostest__test_test_robot_pose_ekf_zero_covariance/testtest_robot_pose_ekf][FAILURE]
> Test Fixture Nodes ['rosbag'] failed
> to launch   PACKAGES:    *
> robot_pose_ekf

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32195/testing-with-rosmake--a--t-fails-because-a-test-failure-failed-to-launch.-what%27s-wrong?/) by [hauptmech](https://answers.ros.org/users/1829/hauptmech/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2012-04-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

robot_pose_ekf requires rosbag to run it's tests, however it's likely that you either do not have rosbag installed or it's not compiled prior to the tests attempting to run.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0